# Understanding ridge regression results

Tags: ridge-regression

I am new to ridge regression. When I applied linear ridge regression, I got the following results:

```
>myridge = lm.ridge(y ~ ma + sa + lka + cb  + ltb , temp, lamda = seq(0,0.1,0.001))
> select(myridge)
modified HKB estimator is 0.5010689 
modified L-W estimator is 0.3718668 
smallest value of GCV  at 0
```

Questions:

- Is it OK to get zero for `GCV`?
- What exactly does it mean?
- Is there a problem with my model?
- How can I find the $R^2$ value of `myridge`?

Comment: Change lamda to lambda. I think the sequence you specified was ignored.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might be better off with the **[penalized](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html)** package or the **[glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)** package; both implement lasso or elastic net so combines properties of the lasso (feature selection) and ridge regression (handling collinear variables). **penalized** also does ridge. These two packages are far more fully featured than `lm.ridge()` in the **MASS** package for such things.

Anyway, $\lambda = 0$ implies zero penalty, hence the least squares estimates are optimal in the sense that they had the lowest GCV (generalised cross validation) score. However, you may not have allowed sufficiently large a penalty; in other words, the least squares estimates were optimal of the small set of of $\lambda$ values you looked at. Plot the ridge path (values of the coefficients as a function of $\lambda$ and see if the traces have stabilised or not. If not, increase the range of $\lambda$ values evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are getting a 0 GCV is because you used:

myridge = lm.ridge(y ~ ma + sa + lka + cb  + ltb , temp, **lamda** = seq(0,0.1,0.001))

instead of

myridge = lm.ridge(y ~ ma + sa + lka + cb  + ltb , temp, **lambda** = seq(0,0.1,0.001))